# Copy games from friends ps4 to your own ps4

Tags: ps4

I want to know if it is possible to copy games, which you and your friend already own, like free PS+ games, and paste them on your PS4 system without downloading them yourself. I have a slow internet connection so I cannot download them myself. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: PS4 games are linked to an account instead of a console. it's not as simple as grabbing a USB stick and saying "COPY ALL GAME FILES"

Comment: Yes i know there is a licence linked to the account, but we both have purchased the same games(which i want to copy)

Answer (score 2):

To my surprise it's possible! But it will completely erase what you already have on your PS4:

> When you transfer data, all data saved on your new PS4™ system is deleted

Exact steps are the following:

> 1. Connect your new PS4™ system and your current PS4™ system to the same network.
> 2. On your new PS4™ system, sign in to PlayStation™Network. 
>      If an update file containing the latest version of the system software is available, a screen appears to guide you through the update process. Follow the on-screen instructions to perform the update.
> 3. Connect your current PS4™ system directly to your new PS4™ system with a LAN cable.
> 4. On your new PS4™ system, select  (Settings) > [System] > [Transfer Data from Another PS4]. 
>      Follow the on-screen instructions.

So, you can move all your friend's stuff to your PS4, then add your own account again and use your own account to access all moved games. Your friends saves will be accessible only for his account.

If you decide to take this route, **don't forget to backup your saves / screenshots / videos / whatever else you have to usb.**

Source: [Transfer Data from Another PS4](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/gb/ps4/settings/transfer.html).

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible but the game must not be on the CD but on the PS4 (from PS store).

Some steps to follow:

1. buy and download the chosen game on a new user signed up with the PS network
2. move the game to an external device (USB over 200GB)
3. sign in with the user that bought the game on an other PS4
4. now the game appears free; just connect the external device in order to move the game on the PS4 without downloading